# How to Develop UI part for java web application using Drag and Drop control?

Tags: html, jakarta-ee

Can you please tell me Is there a way to Develop a UI part for java Web application using DRAG & DROP control(Button,TextBox) option like Windows Application with Latest technology(HTML5,etc).Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web application will be in html, jsp etc for that you can use dreamweaver to add DRAG and DRop control.

Comment: Can you tell which is the best one 1.Dreamweaver or 2.Adobe Flex.Please suggest me the best tool to use easy,faster and effective.

Comment: I prefer Dreamweaver but I don't have much idea about Adobe Flex

Comment: I am using Dream weaver now but,i would like to know about "Adobe Flex".